# How does ki work in Black Clover?

Tags: tropes, black-clover

In Black Clover, people has mana and ki. Mana is an energy source for magic and ki is.. well, that's what I want to ask. We know Asta can sense others through ki, but is there anything else? Does ki give people some power like in Dragon Ball? Is  knowing it useful for any other thing? How does ki work in Black Clover?

Answer (score 3):

[Ki](https://blackclover.fandom.com/wiki/Ki) is a special kind of natural energy  (Originating from Captain Yami's homeland), which is very different from mana. Unlike mana, all living and non -living  things give off Ki when they move.

In other words, the ability to sense Ki, gives individuals the ability to sense attacks by people and projectile objects. Also, the fact that Ki depends more on motion makes it useful in detecting things which have no mana. An example is anti-magic; since Asta normally has no magic, Mages who sense thier surrounding for magic will be unable to detect him, however, using Ki Asta wil be able to detect his opponents, their attacks and also how much anti-magic is circulating through him.

> Further training in Ki could even help predict enemy attacks and in certain cases tell if someone is lying.

Comment: That's a different ki than in Dragon Ball where only living beings have ki. But anyway, is that all? Didnt they mention or imply in some episode that ki was related to Asta's transformation?

Answer (score 0):

The **Advantages** of mastering Ki are below:

1. You can predict movements of enemy beforehand through they're internal energy flow.
2. As Yami will have mentioned in many instances if someone is lying he could sense the ki getting changed.
3. If you master Ki you can be able to dodge attacks from spatial users.
4. Based on the Ki you can check for a person's power if they are weak or strong.

**Disadvantages:**

1. If you are a person who is one with the nature, then you can spread your Ki around with your surroundings where it might not help for a master in ki to recognize you.
2. If you are a basic learner of Ki it will be hard for you to separate from living to non-living things since in black clover everything has Ki.